# C++ passing QDomDocument pointer recursive

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, recursion

I have a little problem with passing a QDomDocument pointer recursive.

Maybe you can tell me what I've overlooked.

```
QString Node::asXML()
{
QDomDocument *doc = new QDomDocument();

QDomElement ele = doc->createElement(typeInfo());
doc->appendChild(ele);

foreach (Node *child, children)
{
    qDebug() << "Node: " << child->name;
    child->recurseXML(doc, ele);    
}

return doc->toString();
}


void Node::recurseXML(QDomDocument *doc, QDomElement parent)
{
QDomElement node = doc->createElement(typeInfo());
parent.appendChild(node);

QMapIterator<QString, QVariant> i(attributes);
qDebug() << attributes.size();

while(i.hasNext())
{
    i.next();
    node.setAttribute(i.key(), i.value().toString());
    qDebug() << "KEY: " << i.key() << " | VALUE: " << i.value().toString();
}

}
```

I loose the data that i get from the recursion, but I'm not sure why. Probably I've done a pointer mistake but I dont see it. Maybe someone can help me

Regards

Comment: There's not reason to create the QDomDocument on the heap. Create it on the stack and pass it via &doc to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the recurseXML function the parameter *parent* is a local variable. It is not the same QDomElement you created in the asXML function but a copy of it. Change *parent* to a reference or a pointer:

```
void Node::recurseXML(QDomDocument *doc, QDomElement parent)
```

-->

```
void Node::recurseXML(QDomDocument *doc, QDomElement& parent)
```